# Integer price number to float Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I am interacting with an API and it returns the price as in integer, for example:

> 99.59 is returned from the API like this: 9959

> 60.00 is returned like this 6000

> 252.90 is returned like this 25290

I'd love a function that takes in the integer number and turns it to float exactly like the above, so 25290 should be 252.90 and 9959 should be 99.59

Any help Is really appreciated.

Comment: Divide by 100? Is this really a problem?

Comment: do you use the values for some calculations?

Comment: How would you make sure that 25290 should return 252.90 and not 25.290 or 2529.0

Comment: Something like this: (val/ 100).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```js
const formatNumber = (value, precision = 2) => {
    return (value / 100).toFixed(precision);
}

console.log(formatNumber(60000, 3));
console.log(formatNumber(2529));
```

And use that `formatNumber` function for formatting.

Like, `formatNumber(6000, 3)` and it will return something like `60.000`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function and convert the value to a sting, maintain the length and add a dot.

```js
const
    format = integer => integer
        .toString()
        .padStart(3, 0)
        .replace(/(?=..$)/, '.');

console.log(format(0));
console.log(format(9));
console.log(format(19));
console.log(format(9959));
```